# Volume of the projection of the unit cube on a hyperplane

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, volume

Let $C_n\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be the $n$-dimensional cube with side $1$, and let $P_k$ be any $k$-dimensional plane, $k\leq n$. What is the maximal $k$-volume $V_{n,k}$ of the projection of $C_n$ on $P_k$?

Quite obviously, the minimal area should be $1$, obtained by taking $C_n = [0,1]^n$ and projecting it on $\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n|x_{k+1}=\ldots=x_n=0\}$. I think the maximum should be obtained by projecting onto something orthogonal to one of the maximal diagonals of the cube, but I haven't found any proof of this, nor a formula for the volume so obtained.

I am particularly interested in the case $k = n-1$.

---

I got an upper bound for $V_{n,k}$.

We can inscribe $C_n$ in the $n$-ball of radius $\sqrt{n}$. The projection of such a sphere on a $k$-plane is a $k$-ball of radius $\sqrt{n}$ containing the projection of $C_n$. Its volume is
$$V(n,k) = \frac{(n\pi)^\frac{k}{2}}{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{k}{2}\right)}\geq V_{n,k}$$
where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function.

**Conjecture:** As $n,k$ become big we have the asymptotical behavior $V(n,k)\sim V_{n,k}$.

Would anyone care to try to prove this, if not to solve the initial problem?

Assuming the conjecture to be true, we have the asymptotical behavior for $V(n,k)$ given by the estimate of the volume of the $k$-ball for $k\gg 1$:
$$V_{n,k}\sim V(n,k)\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left(\frac{2\pi e}{k}\right)^\frac{k}
{2}n^\frac{k}{2}$$
as $n,k\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: I wonder whether the determinant could help you here.

Comment: @Bitwise Well, it would be possible to calculate the volume of the projection of an $(n-1)$-dimensional face by projecting its edges and taking the determinant, but what about the intersections of the projections of the faces? I will maybe try to use your idea for some particular cases, though.

Comment: The "volume" of the intersection of the hypercube $[0,1]^n$ and the hyperplane $x_1 + \ldots + x_n = \lambda$ has a simple formula: $$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(n-1)!} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\lambda\rfloor} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} (\lambda-k)^{n-1}$$ The $\lambda=\frac{n}{2}$ case should give you an lower bound of $V_{n,n-1}$.

Comment: @achillehui Thank you. Could you write down a derivation of the formula, or refer to some paper/website where it's worked out?

Comment: Bitwise's trivial comment actually works for calculating the projection of the cube onto the complement of $(1,\dots,1)$. You can just take the faces and project them, and take into account that each point will be covered exactly twice. The calculation of the area gives something like $\sqrt n$.

Comment: More generally, see formula (1.2) in http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0081746

Comment: @AlexanderShamov Uh, that's pretty neat, actually. Thanks. Do you think you could get a value for $V_{n,k}$ using the formula? Or at least some good bounds?

Comment: Is there anything known about the case k=3?

Comment: @SimonMarynissen Not that I know of (unless $n=3,4$). Numerical calculations are doable to find special cases.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Actually it is known for n=3,4,5, and 6 (see e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEhLNS5AHss&t=21s. But I am interested in the case for higher n.

Comment: @SimonMarynissen Interesting video. I Don't know anything for higher dimensions. I thought about this problem on and off, but I'm not an expert of discrete geometry/polytopes so I made essentially no progress. Let me know if you find something or if you have any viable ideas!

Answer (score 4):

It happens that the area of the orthogonal projection of a unit $n$-dimensional cube onto a $k$ dimensional space is equal to the area of the projection of the cube on the $(n-k)$-dimensional orthogonal plane.

Hence for $k=n-1$ the answer is very simple: the maximal area of the projection is equal to the diagonal of the cube: $\sqrt{n}$.

Reference: https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/blms/16.3.278

Comment: That is nice! I suspected that relation to hold, but didn't know how to prove it. Thanks a lot for the reference!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @AlexanderShamov, there is the following formula for $k=n-1$: let $u$ be a unit normal vector to the hyperplane, then the area of the projection is given by the formula:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n|\left<u,e_i\right>|=\sum_{i=1}^n|u_i|=\|u\|_1$$
where $e_i$ denotes the $i$<sup>th</sup> basis vector (this is an adaptation of the more general formula (1.2) found in the paper [Projection Bodies](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/340/chp%253A10.1007%252FBFb0081746.pdf?auth66=1389905335_5deec1a41b9b2de64ac1233e4d6dcb58&ext=.pdf), by J. Bourgain and J. Lindenstrauss to our simple case). We want to find the extrema for this formula for $u\in S^n$. We'll use Lagrange multipliers:
$$L(u,\lambda)=\|u\|_1-\lambda(\|u\|_2^2-1)$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u_i}L(u,\lambda)=\operatorname{sgn}(u_i)-2\lambda u_i$$
where we assumed $u_i\neq0$. Thus $\lambda = \frac{1}{2|u_i|}$ must be true for all $i$, and by $\|u\|_2^2=1$ we get that $|u_i|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. Thus the maximal value of the area of such a projection is:
$$V_{n,n-1}=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{n}$$
The problem for $k\neq n-1$ remains open.

Answer (score 1):

For $k \ll n$ it looks like a reasonable idea to split the coordinates into $k$ blocks of length roughly equal $n/k$ and project onto the $k$-space generated by $e_{in/k}+e_{in/k+1}+\dots+e_{in/k+(n/k-1)},i=1,\dots,k$. This projection will be isometric to the cube $[0,\sqrt{n/k}]^k$ (since the whole thing decomposes into the direct sum of $k$ instances of taking the longest diagonal), so $V_{n,k} \ge (n/k)^{k/2}$. Obviously, for larger $k$ - namely, at scale $k \sim \lambda n$, $\lambda$ fixed - we need to allow non-equal lengths of blocks - with this modification this idea gives an exponential lower bound there.

A similarly straightforward upper bound is given by considering the diameter, which is $\sqrt n$, and using an isodiametric inequality. The gap between the two bounds grows exponentially in $k$, which doesn't look like a big deal up to scale $k \sim \lambda n$, at which point it confirms exponential growth of $V_{n,k}$, but leaves the precise exponent unknown.

However, at $k$ really close to $n$ something funny happens. The upper bound becomes hopelessly inefficient. In the regime $k = (1 - \frac{1}{r})n$, $r$ constant or large, I would split the coordinates into $n/r$ blocks of length $r$, take inside each $r$-dimensional subspace the largest $(r-1)$-dimensional projection, which has volume $\sqrt{r}$, and take the direct sum of $(n/r)$ of these, which gives $V_{n,k} \ge r^{n/2r}$. This glues well with the $k = \lambda n$ regime, and provides the correct value for $k = n-\mathrm{const}$. I don't have a nontrivial upper bound here.

**Edit:** Actually, by expressing the cube as an orthogonal sum of two cubes, and taking the corresponding projections onto direct sums, we get the following inequality:

$V_{n_1+n_2,k_1+k_2} \ge V_{n_1,k_1} V_{n_2,k_2}$

All of the lower bounds in my answer follow from this inequality, together with the known values $V_{n,1} = V_{n,n-1} = \sqrt n$.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty understanding what you mean when you speak of "splitting coordinates" and "writing the cube as the direct sum of two cubes". Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Well, if we have a cube $[0,1]^{n_1+n_2} \subset \mathbb{R}^{n_1+n_2} \simeq \mathbb{R}^{n_1} \oplus \mathbb{R}^{n_2}$, and let's say we have two subspaces $V_i \subset \mathbb{R}^{n_i}, i=1,2$, $\dim V_i = k_i$. Then $\mathrm{pr}_{V_1 \oplus V_2} [0,1]^{n_1+n_2} \simeq \mathrm{pr}_{V_1} [0,1]^{n_1} \times \mathrm{pr}_{V_2} [0,1]^{n_2}$, i.e. the projection looks like a product of two projections of lower-dimensional cubes. Therefore, $V_{n_1+n_2,k_1+k_2} \ge V_{n_1,k_1} V_{n_2,k_2}$.

Comment: ... So the first part of the answer is an application of this idea to products of one-dimensional projections, i.e. longest diagonals, and the second part is about using products of projections of dimension $k_i=n_i-1$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Nice! +1