# What is the position of a unit cube so that its projection on the ground has maximal area?

Tags: geometry, optimization, 3d, projective-geometry, solid-geometry

> Consider a unit cube in $\Bbb R^3$. What is a position (up to translation, etc.) of the cube such that its projection on the $Oxy$-plane has a maximal area?

Here is a picture: if the sides of the cube are parallel to the three axis, then the projection is the unit square, with has area $1$. But it is possible to project it so that we get a regular hexagon (like the orange one, below).

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$[image: cube_projection]

I believe that the regular hexagon could be a local maximum for the area of the projection, but I'm not sure. I don't even know how to compute the corresponding area of the orange hexagon (what should be the length of the orange side of one of the six equilateral triangles in the hexagon?).

---

I solved the problem for a unit disk in the space: the area of the projection is $\pi \sin(\theta)$, maximal when the angle $\theta$ is $\pi/2$ ($\theta$ is indicated on the right of the picture).

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$[image]

I also tried for a unit square in $2D$, the maximal area being achieved at $\theta=\pi/4$.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$[image]

A similar question could be asked for a cylinder or a cone instead of a cube (the answer is trivial for a sphere, by the way).

Thank you for your comments!

Comment: [I wrote "the" in my title, but the uniqueness of the maximum is not clear to me.]

Comment: Perhaps try solving it using http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874848/

Comment: The side of the regular hexagon is the same as the side of the cube. For the matrix that represents the projection you can see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725986/construct-orthogonal-projection-for-plane-matrix-form/1727441#1727441

Comment: I assume you are researching the case that the projection is perpendicular to the plan and the object position is changed. If this is the case than for the disk you have the wrong answer - the maximum is the disk area - any projection is smaller - Where the $\pi$ comes from?

Comment: @Moti: yes the maximum is the disk area, which is $\pi r^2$ with $r=1$. I don't understand what you mean by "the object position is changed".

Comment: I see. So actually you say that the maximum is the disk area itself.

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltLUadnCyi0 for the average area.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a convex body, its projected surface area $P$ in viewing direction $v$ is equal to the surface integral
$$P = \oint (n\cdot v)^+\,\mathrm dA,$$
where $n$ and $\mathrm dA$ are the normal and area of the differential surface element, and $$x^+ = \max(x,0) = \begin{cases}x & \text{if $x>0$,} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

For a unit cube, $n$ only takes six possible values $(\pm1,0,0)$, $(0,\pm1,0)$, $(0,0,\pm1)$, each over an area of $1$ square unit, so the integral reduces to
$$P = |v_x| + |v_y| + |v_z|.$$
Subject to the constraint that $\|v\|=1$, this is maximized at $v = \frac1{\sqrt3}(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)$, i.e. projection along a space diagonal, which indeed gives the regular hexagon as the projected shape.

Comment: Is it possible to generalise this to n-dimensional cubes and the projection volume of some subspace of Rn?