# A curious little conjecture about 3D cubes and possible generalizations

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $(C) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a 3D solid cube with center $O = (0,0,0)$ and side length $=1$. Let $(H)$ be the projection of $(C)$ on the plane $z=0$, and $h$ be the smallest positive number satisfying $(C)$ is between two planes $z=h$ and $z=-h$ (points of $(C)$ are allowed to be on those planes).

I notice that, for several cases of $(C)$, **the area of $(H)$ equals $2h$**. So I propose a little conjecture that, indeed, $\text{Area}(H)=2h \; \; \forall (C)$.

I haven't proved this conjecture. Actually, I think that, if it's true, somebody definitely did notice and prove this fact. So I only post it here to learn more. Also, I want to propose some generalizations of this fact. Namely:

**What are the necessary and sufficient conditions of $(C)$ so this fact still holds in $\mathbb{R}^3$?**

**How to rightfully generalize this fact into $n$-cubes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n > 3$)?**

**What are the necessary and sufficient conditions of $(C)$ so this fact still holds in $\mathbb{R}^n$?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the corresponding conjecture for a square in the plane? Can you prove it?

Comment: @EthanBolker The corresponding conjecture is straightforward. And I can prove it: it only needs the 90-degree-rotation symmetry of those squares. I don't know how to generalize that into 3D.

Comment: This is a very nice observation, and it is indeed true! In an earlier post I explain [how to find the projected area of a cube](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1894629/856) (although expressed in terms of a rotated projection axis, rather than a rotated cube). The result follows from this and the fact that the face normals of a unit cube are also its edge vectors.

Comment: @Rahul How can you prove the surface integral identity?

Comment: It's simply the integral of the projected area of each forward-facing differential area element. Since the cube is convex, there is no double-counting.